# VS2012 crash when user control attempts to access file

Tags: winforms, file-io, user-controls, visual-studio-2012

I am building a windows forms application (C#).  I have created a reasonably complex custom user control, works great. Problem is, when I add this control to my main form it crashes VS some time later.

After looking around about this I found the suggestion that I use two instances of VS, one to debug the other - this quickly narrowed in on the problem:

The custom user control contains a 30 second timer which saves some data to an XML file when it completes.  As the program is not actually running, it is attempting to save the file to *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE* , where it does not have permission (thus the crash).

This is an unusual problem, as when the application is running normally it will not be a problem (the file is set to save in the same directory as the executable).  Is there a way to prevent the control from running while in design mode?

Comment: Have you looked at the `DesignMode` property of the control?

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I disabled the timer while in DesignMode, this seems to have fixed the problem, thanks.